# CAPS LOCK через кнопку CAPS и кнопку SHIFT, но с контекстом | C++

Tags: c++, клавиатура, char, символы

Вот что у меня есть:

```
#include "types.h" // Содержит типы переменных
// Что-то
void printf(char*);
// Что-то
uint32_t KeyboardDriver::HandleInterrupt(uint32_t esp) {
    uint8_t key = dataport.Read();
    if(key < 0x80) {
        switch(key) {
            case 0x02: printf("1"); break;
            case 0x03: printf("2"); break;
            // И так далее куча символов
```

Этот код и еще немного кода, который я не включил сюда, отвечает за то, чтобы работала клавиатура в OS. Если какой-то символ не указан здесь, но его нажали, то выводится следующее:
`KEYBOARD hexnumber`, пример: `KEYBOARD 0x5B`, это пуск.

Вот что мне надо: сделать так, чтобы кнопка CAPS LOCK работала и выводились заглавные буквы. То же самое с зажатым SHIFT, чтобы он выводил заглавные буквы и символы при нажатии на цифры на верхней панели клавиатуры. **ОЧЕНЬ ВАЖНО** не использовать стандартные библиотеки. Ах да, мне не нужно, чтобы вы прописали каждый символ, с этим я справлюсь. Мне нужна сама суть, как сделать эти кнопки рабочими в этом контексте?

## ПОМОЩЬ

SHIFT: `0x2A`
 CAPS: `0x3A`

Спасибо заранее! Язык C++

Comment: Непонятно, что надо сделать. Когда пришёл код этих двух кнопок выводить какой-то текст прописными буквами? Можно завести флаг, отвечающий за это, и выставлять его при нажатии и отпуске клавиш, например

Comment: Мне и непонятно, как этот флаг создавать...

Comment: Я имею в виду обычный флаг, `bool is_lower_case{};`, например. Выставляете в `true` в событии "отпустили клавиши", в `false` - "зажали клавиши"

Comment: Можешь в ответ конкретно код этого флага написать?

Comment: Так я всё вроде написал уже, что касается создания и выставления флага. А как у вас события эти словить я не знаю, вы это в вопросе не привели

Comment: Создание и выставление флага =/= код флага. Я в С++ плохо разбираюсь и понял только то, что надо мониторить нажатия кнопки шифт, что я не знаю, как делать и пришел сюда за этим. Напиши, пожалуйста, код флага.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что ваш вопрос заключается в том, что "как отследить зажатие и отпуск 2 указанных клавиш"? Или вы знаете, как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, примерно так. И после этого мне надо понять, как отталкиваясь от этого, изменять символы, что я тоже не не знаю, как делать в таком случае

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109547/discussion-between-leopardl-gd-and-).

Comment: [Каждая клавиша основного поля клавиатуры генерирует два типа скэн-кодов: "код нажатия", когда клавиша нажимается, и "код отпускания (освобождения)", когда клавиша отпускается.](https://ru.bmstu.wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)  пожалуй это главное, что требуется для понимания принципов работы с клавой (упаришься, пока найдешь сейчас в сети человеческое описание)

Comment: @LeopardLGD, не лишним, наверное, будет -- [Interrupts are a vital part of sequencing a modern computer. They were developed for exception handling and were later applied to I/O events.](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~mark/interrupts.html) / Создавая свое, не забывайте -- все мы стоим на плечах гигантов...

Comment: Интеррапты я тоже прописал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измени код на такой:

```
#include "types.h" // Содержит типы переменных
// Что-то
void printf(char*);
// Что-то
uint32_t KeyboardDriver::HandleInterrupt(uint32_t esp) {
    uint8_t key = dataport.Read();
    static bool Shift = false;
    if(key < 0x80) {
        switch(key) {
            case 0x02: if(Shift) printf("!"); else printf("1"); break;
            case 0x03: if(Shift) printf("@"); else printf("2"); break;
            // И так далее куча символов
            case 0x2A: case 0x36: Shift = true; break;
            case 0xAA: case: 0xB6: Shift = false; break;
```

Как разобраться с капсом - не знаю.